# How to query by Node ID in esy.osm.pbf

Tags: python, openstreetmap

I've written the following Python code to query airports in Greater London:

```
osm = esy.osm.pbf.File('/Users/michael.nares/Downloads/greater-london-latest.osm.pbf')
airports = [entry for entry in osm if entry.tags.get('aeroway') == 'aerodrome']
for airport in airports:
    print(airport)
```

What it prints is

```
Node(id=7239209757, tags={'name': 'Rushett Farm Airstrip', 'aeroway': 'aerodrome', 'addr:city': 'Chessington (Surrey)'}, lonlat=(-0.3140882999999996, 51.33698640000012))
```

for a Node and

```
Way(id=166164837, tags={'ref': 'NHT', 'iata': 'NHT', 'icao': 'EGWU', 'name': 'RAF Northolt', 'aeroway': 'aerodrome', 'landuse': 'military', 'military': 'airfield', 'operator': 'Royal Air Force', 'wikidata': 'Q106119', 'wikipedia': 'en:RAF Northolt'}, refs=(1776455130, 271241865, 271241866, 271241867, 1776455066, 271241868, 271243205, 271241870, 271241871, 254473245, 271245583, 271245584, 271241874, 271245586, 271241876, 254473250, 271241878, 271241879, 271245637, 254473255, 254473256, 271245639, 254473258, 271245640, 271245641, 271245643, 271241886, 254473268, 254473270, 271246155, 271241892, 271246160, 254473278, 254473281, 271246167, 254473284, 271241897, 271246171, 271246144, 254473292, 254473294, 254473295, 254473297, 254473301, 271241908, 254473305, 271241910, 4576039761, 271241912, 254473309, 271241916, 7740709235, 544301259, 7740709236, 7740709237, 1774062007, 7740709238, 7740709234, 7740709239, 7740709240, 7740709241, 1776455183, 1776455072, 1776455146, 416630859, 7122897725, 271241922, 271241923, 271241924, 271241925, 271241926, 271241927, 271241858, 1776455117, 7740702918, 1776454995, 1776455016, 1776455179, 1776455070, 1776455122, 1776455131, 1776455130))
```

for a way.

What I'm trying to achieve is to be able to draw a shapefile for each airport.  Is there a way of querying the Node IDs to get a list of latitudes and longitudes which can then be turned into  a shapefile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you already found a way to accomplish your goal?
QGIS with can filter by tags, with QuickOSM. Then you can select those features, and batch save them out as shapefiles.

Comment: OK, how I approached it was to get the shape for a given geometry, e.g. a given airport, using OSMNX the Python library.